# Добавить символы в каждый элемент списка

Tags: python

Есть список

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

нужно добавить к каждому символу ':', вот так:

```
a = [':1',':2',':3',':4',':5']
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? В цикле проходите по массиву. Берете каждый элемент, приводите его к строке, добавляете перед ней двоеточие, кладёте в массив по нужному индексу. Вы пытались сами решить задачу?

Comment: @МихаилРебров да попытался, не получилось к сожелению, вот попросил помощи.

Comment: в том что Вы попытались и не получилось нет абсолютно ничего страшного.  За это тут Вам никто ничего не скажет.

Comment: но вот когда пользователи просто хотят чтобы за них другие решили задачу тут не любят и могут заминусовать и удалить такой вопрос. Поэтому когда задаете вопрос старайтесь уделить внимание и описать что именно у вас вызывает затруднение и в чем у вас возникают сложности. Если есть код попытки (пусть и нерабочей) прикладывайте. Так Вам помогут гораздо быстрее. А если Ваш вопрос будет выглядеть как копипаста задания, то на такой вопрос сообщество скорее всего отреагирует негативно.

Comment: Вы можете почитать справку о том как задавать хорошие вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking Чем больше Ваш вопрос будет соответствовать правилам и рекомендациям сообщества, тем быстрее и лучше вы будете получать ответы. Удачи Вам!

Comment: @МихаилРебров понимаю вас, спасибо за рекомендации, и вам удачи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = [':{}'.format(number) for number in a]
```

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы не поменялся `id(a)`:

```
a[:] = [f':{el}' for el in a]
```